# How JQuery to get this.textbox val with kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
    <tbody role="rowgroup"><tr>
  <td role="gridcell">input</td>
  <td role="gridcell">1</td>
  <td role="gridcell">
    <input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 4px">
    <input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="220" style="margin: 4px">
    <input class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 4px">   
    </td>
  <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">
  </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr class="k-alt" role="row">
    <td role="gridcell">input</td>
    <td role="gridcell">2</td><td role="gridcell">
    <input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 4px">
    <input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="59" style="margin: 4px">
    <input class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 4px">
      
    </td>
    </tr>
      
    </tbody>
```

[image]

**Top code was kendo ui grid output, Like top Picture**

**And I want (when i tap this input 1 ->textbox ) i need get '220' on Jquery**

**when i tap this input 2 ->textbox ) i need get '59' on Jquery**

**Then i try Jquery code below  But it always get first textBox value. '220' **

```
$(document).on('change', '.txtBox', function (e) {             
    var ds2 = $("#AddGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;        
    var row = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#AddGrid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

    var Txtinput = $("#Txt_test").val();
    debugger;
    ds2.fetch(function () {
       dataItem.txtRealNum = Txtinput;
    })
    $("#AddGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    return;
```

Comment: HI, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: Hi @Swati I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Supplementary information

For example, I changed the first field to 300
If the input is successful, it can be changed to 301 or 299 by pressing the up and down keys

But in the second input 100
The input is successful, but the displayed value will be 300

Comment: One problem i see in your code is duplicate ids . You can change  `$("#Txt_test").val()` to `$(this).val()` see if thats giving you values or not

Comment: Hi @Swati could i ask another question about .CSS

Like top picture, I want Reduce the input textbox width

And my .CSS  
input#Txt_test {
    width: 20px;
}

Comment: use : `input.txtBox { width: 20px; }`

Comment: Hi @Swati I have other question if <id="Txt_test"> this input i want change 'disabled'  or 'Readonly'   how can i do ;

Comment: I try $("#Txt_test").prop('readonly', true); or $("#Txt_test").attr('disabled', true); It cannot work

Comment: use `$(this).prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: but it cannot work for me, it also can input number .
does any idea to add `onkeydown = "return false; `  this to html using JQuery?

Comment: not sure about that . You can ask new question with complete detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed By @Swati

I Change Jquery code

```
var Txtinput = $("#Txt_test").val();
```

to

```
var Txtinput = $(this).val();
```

And it work for me !

Thank @Swati